# Spring aspect for crosscutting process pipeline usage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aspects

I want to use spring aspect for my crosscutting process like a before or after handler in my process execution lifetime.
For example

What I want before a method I want to execute my handler and due to its response I want to finialize myprocess and return custom response.

In example in stop condition should I throw custom exception to stop process that time how can I handle my return response ,I want to give meaningfull object at the client.What is the best way to do that?

```
@Before
MyHandler()
{

bool stop=checkvalue();
if(stop==false)
continue...
else
{
  //break all process
    and return custom response to client
  //throw exception but meaningfullresponse??
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Before` advice, I would use `Around` advice to wrap the method invocation and call `checkValue()` on beforehand:

```java
@Around("someJoinpoint")
public Object MyHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    if (!checkvalue()) {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } else {
        return someCustomResponseToClient();
    }
}
```

More info on `Around` advice can be found in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-defn).